# Is this Regular Expression Correct: How would you improve it

Tags: c#, regex

I am attempting to edit a string using Regular Expressions in C#. After reading my intended outcome below; are my regular expressions correct and if not how can I improve them?

> Methodology:
>
> - For every "{" char: ensure that it doesn't sit on an empty line (leading & trailing whitespace & format characters consitute an empty
>     line)
> - For every "}" char: ensure that it sits on its own line with no other text

For example: Convert from this:

```
string super
\v\t { abc

    colour "red" }
```

To this:

```
string super { 
abc

    colour "red" 
}
```

My Code:

```
public string[] formatFileContents(string fileContents) {
  Regex openBrkRgx   = new Regex(@"([\c\s]+){");
  // does \c capture whitespace chars?

  fileContents       = openBrkRgx.Replace(fileContents, "{\r\n");

  Regex closedBrkRgx = new Regex(@"[\d\w]}[\d\w]"); 
  // is the above regex comprehensive in your opinion - 
  // ie, can you think of areas where this might fail?

  fileContents       = rgx.Replace(fileContents, "\r\n}\r\n");      
}
```

Comment: Have you tried your code?

Comment: For what definition of `improve`? Faster? Lower memory footprint? More correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you use `\d` in second regex? You replaced digits. I guess, that following code more correctly:

```
const string delimeters = @"[\t\r\n\v\b\s]";

var openBrkRgx = new Regex(delimeters + "*{" + delimeters + "?");
fileContents = openBrkRgx.Replace(fileContents, " {\r\n");

var closedBrkRgx = new Regex(delimeters + "*}" + delimeters + "?");
fileContents = closedBrkRgx.Replace(fileContents, "\r\n}\r\n");
```